# Running AWS cli command using Subprocess

Tags: json, python-3.x, aws-cli

I am just trying out to see if it's valid to use AWS cli commands using subprocess module.
Running the below command gives the successful output

```
vpc = subprocess.run("aws ec2 describe-vpcs | jq -r '.Vpcs[].VpcId'", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

While running the with select statement in jq shown as below gives an error.

```
subnets = subprocess.run("aws ec2 describe-subnets | jq -r '.Subnets[] | select(.Tags[].Value == "az1") .SubnetId'", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

error as

```
File "awsinit.py", line 42
    subnets = subprocess.run("aws ec2 describe-subnets | jq -r '.Subnets[] | select(.Tags[].Value == "az1") .SubnetId'", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
                                                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any guide on fixing this or any other suggestion on this?

Answer (score 1):

Fixing the quotation marks will help you solve the problem

```
subnets = subprocess.run('''aws ec2 describe-subnets | jq -r '.Subnets[] | select(.Tags[].Value == "az1") .SubnetId' ''', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Comment: do you know how I can include variables inside the command?